# "Failed to Export" when exporting an OVA/OVF package from XenCenter

Tags: virtualbox, xen

I need to create a Xenserver inside of a VirtualBox so that I can install a very old Linux distribution and import it into Amazon EC2 as a new AMI.  Everything was going smoothly using bridge networking in Virtual Box with Xenserver installed on it.

Now, when I went to export my new VM to an OVA/OVF file, I consistently run into the error "Failed to Export" in XenCenter.  I can export an XVA file, but that doesn't really help.  How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out what's going on, you need to find the debug log.  In XenCenter, go to Help -> View XenCenter Log Files.  Then, in my XenCenter.log file, it said something like:

```
2015-07-25 19:58:19,739 DEBUG XenOvfTransport.iSCSI [15] - Connecting virtual disk 59f19215-752a-480f-a21a-4bf781d9a967 ... 
2015-07-25 19:58:40,735 ERROR XenOvfTransport.iSCSI [15] - Failed to connect to virtual disk via iSCSI. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.6:3260
2015-07-25 19:58:45,736 ERROR XenOvfTransport.Export [15] - Failed to transfer virtual disk c:\temp\CentOS 5.2\59f19215-752a-480f-a21a-4bf781d9a967.vhd.
System.Exception: Failed to export. ---> System.Exception: Failed to transfer virtual disk c:\temp\CentOS 5.2\59f19215-752a-480f-a21a-4bf781d9a967.vhd. ---> System.Exception: Failed to connect to virtual disk via iSCSI.
```

The trick for me was to go into VirtualBox and change the machine's settings.  Under "Network", look for "Promiscuous Mode" and set it "Allow all".